# Is it OK to use the request url to store cache keys?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using the request url to store cache keys. I am storing the request url to cache data. I would like to know if this is the best way to store cache keys. is there a better way to do this

Comment: Cache keys to what? Can you add more details?

Comment: Its for caching data for a web page

Comment: Cacheing on the client? You shouldn't have to mess with that. If the client wants to cache something, it will. Usually it's the other way around: you want to force the client to NOT cache a page.

Comment: I am caching on the server side. I am caching objects from the database to asp.net cache

Comment: I didn't know you can cache data on the client side. Is there information on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you are passing the keys in the url for which you need to obtain values (from cache)? Or are you saying that you are literally using the query string as your source for cache keys?  Either way, check out the Cache-Aside Pattern.  You should utilize some sort of repository pattern to first check the ASP.NET cache for objects and either return them or go retrieve them (in your case from the database) if they do not exist.  The cache "keys" should be kept as constants possibly in a static class or maybe in a resource file. (If I understand what you are asking)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit confused on what you are asking, but if you just want a suggested way to store some data from a client on the server side, but not persist this data, why don't you store it in the session?

Answer (score 0):

Why not cache the data in the Session variable?